# Get Appium automation element in runtime

Tags: c#, uwp, automated-tests, appium, appium-desktop

I need to create automation system-level test for control.
Control is set by style and have `ListView` with separate `ListViewItem` template.
And my goal is to get text from the header inside this `ListViewItem`.
Here is what I have in XAML (code simplified)

```
<Style>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer">
                            <ScrollViewer.TopHeader>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <ListView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding SomeSource}"
                                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}">
                                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <ItemsStackPanel/>
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    </ListView>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ScrollViewer.TopHeader>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And template for `ListViewItem` is something like:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextName"
                       AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{Binding SomeId}"
                       Text="{x:Bind SomeText}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Of course `ListViewItems` are generating automatically in runtime. They are binded to according property and got needed template.

But in test I can't reach my `TextBlock` anyhow (`ById`, `FindElementById` and so on).
I can find elements by firstly finding `ListView` by class (`FindElementByClassName`), then `ListViewItems` by class, then `TextBlock` by class, but I think it is not the right way. Because in future structure of control could be changed and it will be harder to support tests.

Control have `AutomationPeer` as the Grids too.

So do you have any ideas why I can't get my simple `TextBlock` or even `ListViewItem`s by their `AutomationId`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved by creating custom Automation peer for conrtol. Control inherits ListView (wasn't clear in problem description). So there was problems with listview inside listview-inherited control by Automation id.

Also was helpfull adding `Thread.Sleep()` or `Task.Delay()` for a couple of seconds after element shown but before element finding by WinAppDriver.
Looks like test environment need more time to bind and find elements.